# Grounding shortened vertical antenna with coils?

Tags: rf, antenna, grounding, coil, ham-radio

The calculated coil for 27 MHz shortened vertical antenna with the length of 5cm and 0.2 mm diameter is about 65uH. It is unrealistic with that bandwidth and efficiency, but it serves theoretical for this question.
This coil will be set at the bottom of antenna. I know that the grounding will be important. For the grounding, I will use metal sticks which radiate at the bottom where the coil has been set on. I have the following question. Do I need to use coils with the same value as mentioned above for the grounding metal sticks which have the length of 5cm each, too?

[image: antenna] 
Image from: [Vertical Antenna Calculator | 66pacific.com](https://www.66pacific.com/calculators/quarter-wave-vertical-antenna-calculator.aspx)

The choice between using metal sticks or a ground plane is not technical important. Obviously, there is no need to use coils for ground plane. In conclusion, there is no need to set coils upon metal sticks which are soldered to each other, too.

Edit:

I have just soldered an antenna with the reason to try it out on a 27 MHz radio transmitter. It seems maybe ugly, but it will be an experiment for this evening. I hope it will help.

The issue is not the efficiency here as I predicted above, but the grounding. The bobbin at the bottom is the RF input (+) and the four leg chassis
is the ground (-).

[image: antenna]

Comment: Just how much shortening are you expecting, realistically..?  With what bandwidth, efficiency?

Comment: Can you show the equation for calculating the base loading coil (maybe link to a web calculator or pdf document).

Comment: <https://www.wireantennas.co.uk/antenna-loading-coil-calculator>

Comment: <https://www.george-smart.co.uk/cgi-bin/lfmf_erp.cgi>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory an antenna can be as short as you want. Making an antenna shorter its directivity decreases because antenna size and the wavelength are dependent, but if it was originally a vertical quarter wave whip with ground plane making it shorter wouldn't  affect the radiation pattern.

But making the antenna whip shorter without changing the transmitter frequency has another serious drawback. To make the antenna radiate as much power as the full size version radiated you must increase the AC current in the antenna. To make it happen you must have a matching network which transforms the antenna to look for the transmitter same as the unshortened version and compensates all reactive power at the transmitting frequency. That's because the shortened antenna looks like it has a series capacitance and maybe only a miniscule radiation resistance. A well calculated coil can compensate the reactive power but the matching circuit which makes the antenna look right to the transmitter for full output power has more parts.

The matching network design is no problem in theory if the antenna is known, but the high current can cause hefty losses in the resistance of the metal as well in the matching network and in the antenna itself. It's well possible that most of the transmitter power is dissipated in those resistive losses and not at all radiated to the space. I'm afraid the case is just this if you try to make a 27 MHz transmitter output its full power to a 5 centimeter long whip.

How to calculate the extra losses caused by shortening the antenna + inserting the needed matching network? How to optimize - to make a compromise which allows somehow good radiation power, too?

That cannot be answered in this website. Good solutions can be found from antenna handbooks. Antenna and transmitter engineering knowledge + good rf measuring tools are a must for any optimization. It cannot be handled by giving a couple of simple formulas. Sorry.